# Minimal BASH like line editing is supported GRUB Error on every boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bash, boot-repair

Everytime I boot up, the  Minimal BASH like line editing is supported GRUB  window appears and I have to enter *normal* to get back to the GRUB menu and get things done like normal as before. I have dual-booted Ubuntu along with Windows and have been using it for around 6 months. This GRUB window started showing up out of nowhere. How do I directly boot to the GRUB menu like before instead of this Minimal BASH like line editing window?

Comment: Often from an older grub where newer grub installed to different place or not correctly installed. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: when I saw this screen all I did was type in 'exit' and hit enter... then I was able to bring up grub as normal.